# Appcache limits for HTML5 Web Apps (iOS 5) iPad 1 and iPad 2

Tags: ipad, html, ios5, local-storage

Has the application cache limit(appcache/web SQL/local storage) changed with iOS 5 for the older generation iPad 1? From what I have read, you are limited to the following:

- **5MB** of Appcache
- **5MB** of local storage
- **50MB** of Web SQL DB

Has any of this changed for iOS 5? Also has anyone pushed this limit on an iPad 1?

My next project requires about 2200 images to be cached on a device which is pushing it to say the least. However I think all of the images total around 32mb. I was not sure if I would run into any memory/processor limitations. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have pushed the limit for appCache to 50MB on iOS5.

Comment: can you explain how to push the limit to 50mb for ios5 ... im having html assets of 35MB

Comment: Yes, please explain how you achieved this.

I'm working on some client side db stuff that will basically expand localStorage to actually be backed by many other things, including an appacache hack. Client side db stuff means much more native like experiences can begin to form.